# How can I get Windows to work again?

Tags: windows-7, windows

Long story short, I did a bunch of themeing on my Windows 7 laptop. It worked great for a while. Then explorer.exe crapped out on me. The themeing process had me rename the original file so I could have it as a backup. It gives me the error that it's not a valid Win32 application.

I gave up on it for a while but it just annoys me that it's sitting there. I went to see if I could fix it today. This time, I was just going to back up my files to an external HDD and reinstall. Turns out, my product key is invalid.

Has anyone ran into the issue with explorer before and/or know how to fix it?

Comment: Do what you want.  Your on topic question isn't clear.  What you should do is a matter of opinion...

Comment: @Ramhound I updated the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a Windows installation CD for the same version, you can use the Recovery Console to try and fix it.

1. Boot from the Windows CD
2. When prompted, click "Repair my computer"
3. Choose "Command Prompt"
4. Type `sfc /scannow /offbootdir=X:\  /offwindir=X:\windows` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (replace X with your boot drive and Windows drive locations)
5. Windows will scan your system files and replace any that are corrupted.  Go watch a movie as this will take awhile.
6. Reboot

If that doesn't fix it, you're probably looking at a fresh install and you'll need a valid CD key for that.  Good luck!

[Source](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/repair-explorerexe-cd-49174.html)

Edit:  I see you got it fixed, but just for anyone else that may stumble upon this answer, the above is for when you're booting off the CD and you're in the Recovery Environment.  You can accomplish the same thing if you can get into Windows by opening an elevated command prompt and running `sfc /scannow`

Comment: The syntax your provided for SFC isn't correct while within the Windows Recovery Environment you might want to fix it.  The syntax you provided will just indicate an error, and a message, saying what I just said.  You might want to verify what the syntax is before you edit your answer I will be checking before i issue my vote